# Removing ng-class

Tags: angularjs

How can I remove ng-class in angular js.

Here is my example code

```
<form name="myform" ng-class="plus">
    //...
    <button ng-click="save()">click</button>
</form>
```

and what I tried but does not work

```
$scope.add_page = function(){
    $scope.myform.removeClass(plus);//what i try but not work
}
```

any suggest how to removed class or remove attribute ?

Comment: This isn't jQuery. You'll have to think differently. Also, what you've done is not the way to use `ngClass`.

Comment: simples way is use ng-class and in your add_page method clear the ng-class variable

Comment: ng-class="plus" then in your function $scope.plus=""

Comment: @cst1992 & @ Arunprasanth K V, so there are no way to remove class `plus`?

Comment: if you want to remove then you can get the particular element and remove class using angular or jquery or javascript syntax. but clearing a class in scope is just same as removing it

Comment: answer of @Hussain Mohd, help me, this is what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

Just change it like this

```
<form name="myform" ng-class="{plus?'plus':''}" ng-init="plus=true">
    //...
    <button ng-click="save()">click</button>
</form>
```

and then in controller

```
$scope.plus=true;
$scope.add_page = function(){
    $scope.plus=false;//what i try but not work
}
```

Comment: you can also toggle it with `$scope.plus = !$scope.plus;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below method

```
<form name="myform" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div ng-class="plus">with class </div>
    <button ng-click="clickme()">
    click me to remove class 
    </button>
</form>
```

Js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.plus="plus";
$scope.clickme=function(){
$scope.plus="";
}
});
```

CSS

```
 .plus{
      background-color:red;
    }
```

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/35541/)

Note : 
You can do the same thing using other methods also.

1) Simply create a class using class instead of ng-class. ng-class is not required here, and then remove it by getting the particular element using id or via event

2) Angularjs is maid on top of javascript only so you can use any of the javascript syntax in angularjs(not a good practice)to remove class .